# java.sql.SQLException: sql injection violation, comment not allow : select

Tags: java, mysql, mapper

As the title says, I use the SQL to select But report the Error. The **SQL** in the **Mapper** below

```
<select id="selectBillDetailByBizIdAndClearType" resultMap="BaseResultMap">
    select
    <include refid="Base_Column_List" />
    from dwd_clearing_bill_detail
    where biz_detail_id in
    <foreach collection="bizDetailIdList" item="item" index="index" open="(" separator="," close=")">
      #{item}
    </foreach>
    and clear_type in
    <foreach collection="clearTypeList" item="item" index="index" open="(" separator="," close=")">
      #{item}
    </foreach>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an exception indicating that building SQL statement this way is insecure.
Someone can inject malicious SQL code, retrieving sensitive data or modify/remove your data. Please see https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have already solved the Error because I have add a blank space, this must be deleted.